# Count Number of objects present on an array under Specific MongoDB ID

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB Data Structure is like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a3a67b102d9d926f8cd66b8"),
    "createdate" : ISODate("2017-12-20T13:37:53.921Z"),
    "groupmember" : [ 
        {
            "membername" : "a",
            "memberid" : "5a20ee1acdacc7086ce7742c"
        }, 
        {
            "membername" : "b",
            "memberid" : "5a20eb5bcdacc7086ce77427"
        }, 
        {
            "membername" : "c",
            "memberid" : "5a20ee35cdacc7086ce7742d"
        }, 
        {
            "membername" : "d",
            "memberid" : "5a20ee67cdacc7086ce7742e"
        }, 
        {
            "membername" : "e",
            "memberid" : "5a20ee9acdacc7086ce7742f"
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Now I want to calculate the total Number of member present on Group member Array.
I have a solution but it will not for Any specific id. 
What I have Solution is like this

```
Test.aggregate([

                {$group:{'_id': '$_id', 'total': { $sum: { $size:"$groupmember" } }}}
            ], function(error, data){
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
        });
```

So this approach returns all count of the database. 
I also tried Match and unwind But it returns blank array. like this

```
Test.aggregate([
                {$match: {_id: '5a3a67b102d9d926f8cd66b8'}},
                {$unwind: "$groupmember"},
                {$group:{'_id': '$_id', 'total': { $sum: { $size:"$groupmember" } }}}
            ], function(error, data){
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
        });
```

Comment: Try `Test.aggregate([{ $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(5a3a67b102d9d926f8cd66b8) } }, { $project: {total: {$size:"$groupmember"}}])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
Test.aggregate(
   [
      {
         $project: {
            noOfGroupMembers: { $size: "$groupmember" }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

If you want to do it with id:

```
Test.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $match:"5a3a67b102d9d926f8cd66b8"
      },
      {
         $project: {
            noOfGroupMembers: { $size: "$groupmember" }
         }
      }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Not work. Error is (node:8244) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: the match filter must be an expression in an object

Comment: i have update the answer, basically in case of $id you have to use id.

Answer (score 0):

```
Test.find({_id: '5a3a67b102d9d926f8cd66b8'}, function(err, data){
  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    var length = data[0].groupmember.length;
    console.log(length);
  }
});
```